# Cocoa: NSAlert in correct window (2 screens)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am running my Mac OSX application on a computer with two screens. While my application is in the right monitor, I show an alert using:

```
NSAlert* alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:message defaultButton:@"OK" alternateButton:nil otherButton:nil informativeTextWithFormat:@""];
[alert runModal];
```

Sometimes the alert pops up on the left screen, and sometimes on the right screen. Is there a way to force the alert to pop over its active app (meaning - the "correct screen")?

Thanks!
Nili

Answer (score 0):

The alert always pop ups in the screen where you are running the app on, there's no randomness on that. Just tried myself.

Comment: Let's say I'm dragging a file from the left screen to my application, that is on the right screen. The alert will sometimes pop up on the left screen.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `beginSheetModalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo`

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Sheets/Tasks/UsingAlertSheets.html

Comment: Alerts can be on sheet format too. If you want alert attached to a window, I think you should use a sheet at this window.